# Get xlsx full file path from import url are missing value

Tags: android, uri

I get full file path of xlsx file from url. Error show  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Missing volume name: content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/document%3A1000000004

[full code](https://github.com/saparkhid/AndroidFileNamePicker/blob/main/javautil/FileUtils.java)

```
            if ("document".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Files.getContentUri(MediaStore.getVolumeName(uri));
             
            }
```

Comment: You should stop with that getPath() function for your picker as on modern Android devices (Android 11+)  obtaining 'a real path from an uri' makes no sense as even if you manage to do so that path cannot be used as the permission to read/write the file is on the content scheme urie. Not on your path. Or the app should use MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.

Comment: `MediaStore.getVolumeName(uri)` Well you could at least have put that uri in your code here. But it will not be an uri obtained from the media provider so no volume name. They start with content://media/...

Comment: I also had set MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission. Download file have into download folder when I test with Samsung phone, Samsung have return from download provider but OPPO phone return from documents/document/ provider.